# Swift parse data from weird object (almost JSON)

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to get data out of an object which I have not seen yet in swift. The type of the object is `Any`.

```
    func getMetaData(_ callback: @escaping (Error?) -> ()) {
        guard let accessToken = self.credentials?.accessToken
            else { return callback(CredentialsManagerError.noCredentials) }
        Auth0
            .users(token: accessToken)
            .get(profile!.sub, fields: ["user_metadata"], include: true)
            .start { (result) in
                switch result {
                case .success(let user):
                    print(user)
                    self.metadata = user
                    callback(nil)
                case .failure(let error):
                    callback(error)
                }
        }
    }
```

The object came to be as a dictionary `[String:Any]` with any being (`print(user)`):

```
["user_metadata": {
    fname = abc;
    lname = xyz;
}]
```

I got `user_metadata` out and got this:

```
{
    fname = abc;
    lname = xyz;
}
```

This is eventually what I want to achieve:

```
UserMetaData(fname: "abc", lname: "xyz")
```

It's not quite JSON and I have no clue what to do with it

Comment: There isn't a tutorial/documentation on how we can possibly parse "weird objects". Please consider using one of the supported file types for your IDE. Any answer at this moment would be wrong, Because nobody knows what type of file they're working on.

Comment: It looks like the `description` of a dictionary which is a standard collection type.

Comment: Seems like your json is not proper. It should be something like this  [
 { "user_metadata" : {
    "fname" : "abc",
    "lname" : "xyz"
  }
 }
] . You can check your json in this link https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as vasian said, I casted the inner object to a dictonnary providing me with an `Optional(fname: "abc", lname: "xyz")` which I could use!

#### typealias (standard with Auth0)

`typealias ManagementObject = [String : Any]`

#### inside the SessionManager.getMetaData()

`self.metadata = (meta["user_metadata"] as! ManagementObject)`

#### when I needed to get the data

```
let firstName = SessionManager.shared.metadata!["fname"]! as! String
let lastName = SessionManager.shared.metadata!["lname"]! as! String
```